# SFTP using Python 2.4.3

Tags: python, .net, sftp, paramiko

I need to SFTP a file from my local to a remote server.

I have reviewed the [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) and we can not use this as this only supports versions greater than 2.6.

**What are my alternative to do SFTP using python 2.4.3**

Comment: why was this down voted if you couldn't answer .

Comment: try paramiko versions earlier than this: 1.12.3, 2014-03-13

Comment: @denfromufa I have tired paramiko . This doesn't exist in 2.3 of python.

Comment: You need to install it with pip or easy_install

Comment: @denfromufa I am afraid i am not the sys admin on those machines. Would you think installing those have any negative affect on the operating systems.